Understanding AWS Fargate Memory Utilization
I'm trying to wrap my head around memory utilization that shows 839,000,000% usage in the AWS console. This is for a single AWS ECS Fargate service with a single task running (Linux/X86_64 .25 vCPU, .5 GB, platform v1.4.0). For months, the memory utilization has been around 10-15%, and then all of a sudden, the AWS console started showing 839m% utilization. No noticeable impact to the service's CPU utilization or overall performance, which leads me to believe this is an AWS metrics bug. Not sure what to make of this, as it's not possible for this to use 4+ petabytes of memory!
Is there something I'm missing that could cause metrics to report utilization this high?
The drop of utilization happened after the service was restarted.


That has to be a bug. I would submit it to AWS support.

I'm seeing something similar for one of our ECS Fargate services right now.  Suddenly it spiked to 26,000,000% MemoryUtilization which seems a bit high. We'll try a rolling restart via update_service/force_new_deployment to see if that clears the issue.
